# How do you make a Android TextView expand to the right?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I have a TextView that updates dynamically with numbers from 1-100.  However, when they get to be 10 or higher, the numbers expand to the left and it shifts the other components in the LinearLayout to the left as well.  Here is what it is doing:

```
__1

_10

100
```

I want it to do this:

```
1__

10_

100
```

The underlines are just denoting spaces.  Thanks!

Comment: `android:gravity="start"`?

Comment: That didn't work.

Comment: Please provide the xml file for the activity

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Assuming this is your case at xml:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_marginStart="350dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
android:text="1"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="181dp" />
```

**Explanation:**

Without a horizontal bias, it will expand in both directions because the default bias is '**0.5**'.

On the other hand, setting the horizontal bias to '**0**' will cause it to expand only to the right and vice versa.

Therefore, we specify a margin left (this can be 0 if you wish) along with the start and end constraints. Subsequently, specify the horizontal bias to '0'.

**Solution:**

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Comment: Providing more than just "... this worked for me..." would really help your answer. Along with providing more detail in your answer. Aim to have a response that can be (more or less) understood without needing to refer to the question.

Comment: @Kingsolmn Thanks for the feedback. I have provided more details in my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that.

1 ) android:gravity="start"

2 ) android:textAlignment="viewStart"

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review your answer in the light of the slightly earlier comments posted by @Bruno and the OP. Thanks.